# WCF Identity C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I'am using WCF which are deployed on IIS and I need that WCF will be able to load images on network mapped disk. Can anyone give me an advise how to do that? I reacive on the WCF side an error

> Could not find a part of the path

Thank you

Comment: File.Exists(@"Y:\Photo\img01.jpg") and I get that error. Y drive is mapped. If I put this location to the C: it's working fine.

Comment: I think that problem is in identity, beacause WCF does not have any. So I want some advise how to use identity in C# which can provide me an identity to access to the mapped drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to do anything on C#. Just give Network Credentials to the application pool of your WCF:

1. Select the application pool of Web Service, and then click Advanced Settings in the Actions pane
2. Then click the ... button to open the Application Pool Identity dialog box
3. You can use a built-in account or a Custom account.
4. If you want a custom, click Set to open the Set Credentials dialog box and fill the required Fields.
5. This one is just an advice, always explore the IIS to manage this kind of problems.

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

This site can help you with some problems, and have a quick solution for your problem too, but first read entire article before reachs the command line tool ICACLS, that can be used to do:

```
ICACLS test.txt /grant "IIS AppPool\WebServiceAppPool":Y
```

Or something like that =p

Well, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have AppPool identity set to my login and My login has permissions on that location. The problem is same, that application can not find Y: drive